# What happens to quantum fluctuations near the schwarzschild radius?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes

I was reading about Feynman Diagrams and have gotten the impression that particle/anti-particle pairs are created fairly often given a large space. The surface area of a sphere with a radius equal to the schwarzschild radius is also rather large. What happens to a quantum fluctuation that creates a pair right at the schwarzschild radius?

**My thoughts**

We don't have a complete theory of quantum gravity, but we do have some of the ideas. For example, if an electron is created right behind the schwarzschild radius and an antielectron is created right in front of the schwarzschild radius, the electron can't escape, but the ant-electron has a fair chance of escaping. However if this were to happen, the black hole would've, for all intents and purposes, added energy to the universe. Of course, if electrons/anti-electron pairs are just as likely to be formed inside or outside the black hole, then the fluctuations would cancel over time I guess.

Comment: You are asking about Hawking Radiation and there are many sites that thoroughly describe it.  The black hole does not add energy to the universe.  Per Hawking Radiation, to an observer outside of the S. Radius, the particle that fell into the black hole had negative energy  to balance the positive energy emitted.

Comment: @K7PEH I didn't think so, I'll come back with a new question about Hawking Radiation then...

Comment: The other thing to realize is that virtual particles aren't observable things in any sense.  They are really, fundamentally, just computational tools that make it easier to figure out perturbation theory.  In particular, virtual particles aren't constrained to travel locally at speeds less than $c$, this is something that is only a restriction on causal modes.  So, the virtual particle inside the horizon isn't trapped there.  It's only when it is looked at by an observer far away, with a different notion of "real and virtual particle" that the formerly virtual particle appears "real"

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Didn't know. That's rather interesting.